# Selecting a particular folder in Drive - Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a script that archives files found in another folder, however I am having trouble changing the type from FolderIterator to Folder type.

```
//Global Variables
var classroomFolderName = "Classroom";
var archiveFolderName = "Test Archive";
```

The below code checks to make sure the folders are existing before the script begins to execute

```
function doGet(){
  //Makes sure there is an Classroom folder available 
  try {    
    getFolder(classroomFolderName);
  }

  catch(e){
    if (e == 1){
      Logger.log("Error 1: Classrooms folder not found");
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error 1: Classrooms folder not found"); 
    }

    else if (e == 2){
      Logger.log("Error 2: Multiple Classroom folders found");
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error 2: Multiple Classroom folders found");
    }
  }

  //Makes sure there is an Archive folder available 
  try {
    getFolder(archiveFolderName);
  }

  catch(e){
    if (e == 1){
      //Rather than returning an error, the new archive folder is created
      DriveApp.createFolder(archiveFolderName);
    }

    else if (e == 2){
      Logger.log("Error 3: Multiple Archive folders found");
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error 3: Multiple Archive folders found");
    }
  }
```

This is the section I am having trouble with. I want to use Folder class fuctions on the folders in these iterators. Each iterator will only contain 1 Folder, and I cannot access that one folder.

```
  var classroomFolder = getFolder(classroomFolderName);
  var archiveFolder = getFolder(archiveFolderName);


}
```

Function used to check for file existance

```
function getFolder(folderName){
  var foldercount = 0;
  //Selects all folders named exactally as parameter is given
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  while (folder.hasNext()) {
    var folders = folder.next();
    foldercount++;
  }

  //Throws errors if number of folders != 1
  if (foldercount < 1){
    throw 1;
  }

  else if (foldercount > 1){
    throw 2;
  }

  else{
    return folder;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woops, my mistake, I was emptying the iterator in my getFolder function, without realising it.

Fixed it with the following code.

```
  var classroomFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(classroomFolderName).next();
  var archiveFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(archiveFolderName).next();
```